# Why am I getting an unexpected token error in React when using createRef()

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

The error is pointing towards the space right before the `=` in the class.

This is the error
 `C:\Users\crism\dream-in-green\src\components\myLineGraph.js:5:13: C:/Users/crism/dream-in-green/src/components/myLineGraph.js: Unexpected token (5:13)`

It also says that the `chartRef` in the first line of code is never being used even though it's being called in the line below the class.

Any ideas?

```
import React, { Component, chartRef } from 'react';
import Chart from "chart.js";

export default class LineGraph extends Component {
    chartRef = React.createRef();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think chartRef should be declared as const instead of importing it from react library

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way to do it:
`this.chartRef = React.createRef();`
You don't need to declare it at the top of the file